# Change the text's font in current layer in Photoshop using AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, photoshop

I want to change the text's font in current layer in Photoshop using AppleScript, but I am new to AppleScript. By looking up the Photoshop's script dictionary, I know how to reach to the current layer so far:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC 2018"
    tell current document
        tell current layer
            ... <= What should I do next?
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

But I don't have clue what to do next, I can't find related properties in the dictionary to continue to reach the text in the layer. Could somebody shed some light on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out the solution:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC 2018"
    tell current document
        tell current layer
            if kind is text layer then
                set font of text object to "<font-name>"
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```